# chan chan construct causing deadlock

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I'm trying to understand the `chan chan` construct in Go by writing a small piece of code as shown below where I want 3 worker subroutines to work on 10 jobs. Each worker subroutine has its own channel where it receives "jobs" to work on. The main Go routine distributes the jobs to the worker's channel by getting a channel from a pool of channels(hence the `chan chan` construct).

However this code results in a deadlock situation! I've tried a few variations of this code but got the same error.

Is it because the worker subroutines are waiting forever to read a job from its channel? Or is it due to something else(maybe channel closed prematurely etc.)? I'm clearly missing something in my understanding of the whole construct.

Can someone please help me understand the issue and how to fix it?

Code in [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/dC7oyNkd7hP) and also copied below on request.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Job struct {
    ID int
}

func worker(id int, jobs <-chan Job, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Printf("Worker %d starting\n", id)
    for job := range jobs {
        fmt.Printf("Worker %d processing job %d\n", id, job.ID)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Worker %d done\n", id)
}

func main() {
    numWorkers := 3
    maxJobs := 10
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    // Create the pool of worker channels
    pool := make(chan chan Job, numWorkers)

    for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
        workerChan := make(chan Job) // Create a new channel for each worker
        pool <- workerChan           // Add the worker channel to the pool
        go worker(i, workerChan, &wg)
    }
    defer close(pool)
    // Create jobs and distribute them to workers
    for i := 0; i < maxJobs; i++ {
        job := Job{ID: i}
        wg.Add(1)
        workerChan := <-pool
        workerChan <- job
    }

    // Wait for all workers to complete
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("All jobs are processed")
}
```

Comment: It is not the channel of channels causing the deadlock. You have logic errors in your program. Include your code in the question so we can show what's wrong with it.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I've copied my code in the question itself. Can u please help me understand the errors in my logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: you don't need a channel of channels here. To distribute work to multiple workers, you can simply have all workers read from a single shared channel. When you send a piece of work to the channel, if there are available workers, one of them will pick it up, otherwise, channel send operation will block until one becomes available.

If you want to use a separate channel for each worker, you still do not need a channel of channels, you simply need a slice of them. Each worker will listen from a dedicated channel, and you will manage job distribution yourself:

```
numWorkers := 3
maxJobs := 10
var wg sync.WaitGroup
pool := make([]chan Job, numWorkers)
for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
    pool[i] = make(chan Job)
    wg.Add(1)
    go worker(i, pool[i], &wg)
}
for i := 0; i < maxJobs; i++ {
   job := Job{ID: i}
   pool[i%len(pool)] <- job
}
for _,c:=range pool {
   close(c)
}
wg.Wait()
```

Your code has two problems:

1. You should add to the waitgroup when you create a goroutine, not when you send a job to a channel
2. When you read a channel from your channel of channels, that channel is removed from the pool. So after you read 3 channels, `workerChannel := <-pool` will block, because there are no other channels. If you insist on using channel of channels, you have to put it back:

```
 workerChan := <-pool
 workerChan <- job
 pool<-workerChan
```

This way, you use the channel of channels as a circular queue

3. Closing the `pool` will not achieve anything. You have to close the channels in `pool`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the corrections Burak! I could get the code to work finally and now I understand the concept much better. Working code - https://go.dev/play/p/DfOGQrxMoSO
One followup though - Is this channel of channels construct used anywhere in production or is the slice of channels the right way to go about solving this type of "multi-worker" scenarios? Asking this because I was intrigued by the chan chan construct in this blog(https://medium.com/smsjunk/handling-1-million-requests-per-minute-with-golang-f70ac505fcaa).

Comment: There is nothing magical about channel of channels. Channels pass values between goroutines. If you need to pass a channel, then you use channel of channels.

Comment: Hmm sorry I can't think of a practical use-case of channel of channels. Can you please give a practical example of when one goroutine would need to pass a "channel" to another one?

Comment: Here's an example workerpool implementation from my book where it collects results using a chan chan from the pool: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Effective-Concurrency-in-Go/blob/main/chapter5/workerpool/wp2/main.go#L66

Comment: Interesting example! One Result channel for every file that is processed by the worker. I wonder if the same use-case can be solved using a "slice of channels". Maybe not since the number of files which need to be processed is not a constant?

Comment: If you use a slice of channels, you also would need a mutex to serialize access to the slice when you're appending to it or removing from it.

Answer (score 0):

A few small, commented changes

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Job struct {
    ID int
}

func worker(id int, jobs <-chan Job, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Printf("Worker %d starting\n", id)
    for job := range jobs {
        fmt.Printf("Worker %d processing job %d\n", id, job.ID)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Worker %d done\n", id)
}

func main() {
    numWorkers := 3
    maxJobs := 10
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // Create the jobs channel
    jobs := make(chan Job, numWorkers)

    for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
        // Wait group is counting workers running, not jobs in flight
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(i, jobs, &wg)
    }

    // Create jobs and distribute them to workers
    for i := 0; i < maxJobs; i++ {
        jobs <- Job{ID: i}
    }

    // Close channel here so that the workers can exit (range)
    close(jobs)

    // Wait for all workers to complete
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("All jobs are processed")
}
```